# Silent consonants when singing

Tags: pronunciation, song-lyrics, music

I first noticed this odd pronunciation in [the second opening of code geass](https://youtu.be/YBhsDtFUgdM?t=23s). The singer repeatedly pronounces the word かんかく as something that sounds more like かんかう, missing the 'k' sound.

I noticed it again more recently, in the [opening of mondaiji](https://youtu.be/Ie2JS4K69xQ?t=35s), in which かすか is pronounced as かすあ.

I was aware that vowels could be skipped in pronunciation, but these are the only instances I've seen this happen with consonants. While there don't appear to be any other words you could easily mistake these two for when pronounced this way, I'd have thought it'd still cause at least some confusion to pronounce them like this, even if it may better fit the music.

How common is it to remove consonants like this? Does it happen with consonants other than 'k', and are there any words in which it's common to leave a consonant out (like how it's common to leave out the 'u' in 好き)?

Comment: To my ear the /k/ is not missing in either song, but in the first song the following /u/ is at least devoiced if not entirely absent.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm not used to hearing that exact sound in English then? No matter how many times I listen, I can't hear anything. I feel like I can kind of hear it in the first because I'm specifically looking for it, but I can't hear a thing in the second.

Comment: Pop singer like visual kei often sing with english pronounciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it's been a few days and nobody else has added anything, I guess the answer is simply that I can't hear it. Perhaps that's because of me being used to English pronunciation, or perhaps it's just me that can't hear it. Whichever it is, it seems that the consonants are indeed there.

So, short answer is; no, consonants cannot be left out of words.